# Symantec Netbackup: cannot send mail to root on client mydomain.com

Tags: linux, netbackup

Today I ran into a problem with Netbackup 7.6.

When a backup job finishes I get this error message: cannot send mail to root on client mydomain.com

I chose server sends mail and gave an email address in every client properties. Of course I chose the same option in the master server properties.

However I gave email address in client properties I only got only one error(like 2 lines above), and no notification in my mailbox.

So the configuration seems to be fine but it seems to be that the client try to send the notification however I chose that the server sends it.

I tried to add an email address in master server/global attributes and I made a failed job. I got this error message: Error bpbrm(pid=20986) cannot send mail to clientadmin@mydomain.com

The Catalog backup works fine and I get the message about that. And I tried to send email from the master server with sendmail and it also works fine.

Master Server runs in a CentOS 7 server.

Can you suggest me any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Need to install mailx.
Thats solved my problem.